# Questions about "Atomic Structure"

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Well, I'm new on "Physics.SE" and, I'd like to learn if we're allowed to ask, discuss and learn about the "Atomic Structure" and "Electrons" on the "Physics"? If so, I'd love to give it a try very soon and start to enjoy it... :)

Thank you very much!...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

and welcome to the site! Generally speaking, atomic structure and electrons are within the scope of the site, so you can certainly go ahead and ask your questions. Of course, we can only tell whether any given question is appropriate on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some guidelines on what type of questions are generally acceptable:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions